# Computation of order $\overline{23}$ in $(\Bbb Z/36\Bbb Z )^\times$ under multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

This problem occurs when i compute for mod 36, the order of $\overline{23}$ is 6. 
It is very hard to compute all products of 23. i.e, $23, 23^2, 23^3,\cdots$ 
and mod out 36.

Is there any brilliant method to compute its order?

Comment: Euclid's Algorithm on 23 & 36 ... one quickly get the answer 11.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit We are not trying to compute the inverse, but the _order_, i.e. what $j$ makes $23^j\equiv 1$ rather than what $j$ makes $23j\equiv 1$.

Comment: Sorry :-( ... read the question ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *Chinese remainder theorem*:
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/36\mathbf Z&\simeq \mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/9\mathbf Z\\
n\bmod 36&\mapsto(n\bmod4,n\bmod9)
\end{align}
This shows the order of $n$ modulo $36$ is the l.c.m. of its orders modulo $4$ and modulo $9$.

Now $23\equiv -1\mod 4$, hence its order mod. $4$ is $2$, and $23\equiv5\mod 9$, so $23^2\equiv -2\mod 9$, $\;25^3\equiv -2\cdot 5\equiv -1$, $25^6\equiv 1$ (we know the order must be a divisor of $\varphi(9)=6$).

Finally the order of $23$ is
$\;\operatorname{lcm}(2,6)=6.$

Comment: CRT and Lagrange's theorem to the rescue. If I recall correctly, Hensel's lemma helps with prime powers (where CRT doesn't work), but I might be mistaken.

Comment: Yes, you can use Hensel's lifting, but for such small values, it's as simple to do it by hand.